# iOS app size differnce between testflight and Apple store

Tags: ios, mobile, build, size

iOS app build size drastically, when i build and *testflight* its **9Mb**, but when it was approved by Apple in *Apple store* its showing **14Mb**, Can any one tell/help me, How can this is possible? Just wanted to understand the scene behind it.

**NOTE : There is no change in the resource files in both the builds.**

Comment: I guess (but i am not sure) - 9 Mbyte is the File Download Size, and 14 Mbyte is the size it takes on the device.

Comment: I'm agree with @derdida; 9Mb is the archive size and 14Mb is the size taken by app once installed on the phone.